# Request GA statistic data for a specific large set of pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've spent last few days trying to find a solution to solve problem below.

I have set of URLs for which I would like to request data - mainly pageviews and visits by months in specific time interval. These URL specify one web section and we would like to get statistics for this section. I'm using [PHP GAPI](http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/).

I am able to construct correct filter for the URL set:

> ga:pagePath==[url1]||ga:pagePath==[url2]||ga:pagePath==[url3]...

But this works for a fews URLs because request is sent via GET and there is request length limitation for GET.

At first I tried to make severeal requests for a few URLs from the whole set and after all requests (when I had data for all pages) I made sum of pageviews and visits. Than I realized that this could work for pageviews but **not for visits** (one particular visit could be counted in more than one response and thanks to sum it was counted muliple times).

And than i have these limitations:

1. I **can't use regular expresion** to shorten the filter. URLs of pages are badly designed (not thanks to us :) ) and the pages in a web section therefore don't have nice URL prefix like /my-section/*
2. I **need historical data** (2 years back), so it won't help to start tracking some custom variable or event for pages in particular web section from now.

So I tried to make POST request to API. I was able to get auth token, but POSTing request to get statistic data returns:

> 403 Forbidden
>   Target feed is read-only

1. I tried to find if there is actualy the possibility to use POST method, but had no luck finding exact info (some clues suggest that it is not possible).
2. Another idea could be redesigning URL to have some nice prefix to filter by regexp and somehow changing the stored URLs in GA, but I have a feeling that it's not possible either.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?
Thanks for any suggests :)